# Why I import `Common` module still can't use DatePipe in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, module, date-pipe

In my opinion, if `A.module` import `B.module` and `B.module` import `C.module`, it stand that `A.module` import `C.module`. That's the reason why many Angular developers build a public module named `Shared.module`.

However, this rule looks like doesn't apply to `DatePipe`. I have builded a `Shared.module`, the `CommonModule` is imported and exported in this module. Then I import the `Shared.module` in `AppModule`. The official document tell me the `DatePipe` is belongs to `CommonModule`.

Unfortunately, the browser console shows error: `NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DatePipe]:`

You can see the code in below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-common-datepipe?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Who can help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: instead of providing `DatePipe` to the constructor, you could declare it as a member variable as follows: `readonly datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you said is correct. The reason for the above cause is that in **CommonModule**, DatePipe is not registered as a provider.

What you can do is adding DatePipe as a provider in your shared module.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Comment: Only `DatePipe` need manually provide? Or any Angular pipe need that?

Answer (score 3):

Pipes are not injectable in Angular. You have to manually provide them yourself.

```js
@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   providers: [DatePipe]
   // ....
{)
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Only `DatePipe` need manually provide? Or any Angular pipe need that?